# Mapbox my-location drift android

Tags: android, mapbox

I'm using MapBox on Android (tested with Nexus 5x on 7.0 and 7.1) with a fairly simple setup (see below). The odd thing is that the map starts to drift when the phone isn't moving or being used as though I'm walking around. The code sample below is the minimum to replicate. I added an extra location listener and attached one to Mapbox too. The interesting thing is that when I'm drifting there are no logs coming in for the location changing which makes me think it's a bug in the Mapbox SDK (4.1.1).

Any thoughts of what could be going on?

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MapView mMapView;
    private MapboxMap mMap;
    private LocationManager mLocationManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mMapView = (MapView) findViewById(R.id.map);
        mLocationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        mMapView.onCreate();
        mMapView.getMapAsync(this::onMapReady);
        // To keep the example short I'm skipping the permissions.
        mLocationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, GPS_UPDATE_MIN_TIME,
            GPS_UPDATE_MIN_DISTANCE, this::onLocationChanged);
    }

    @Override
    public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle state) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(state);
        mMapView.onSaveInstanceState(state);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        mMapView.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mMapView.onPause();
    }

    private void onMapReader(MapboxMap map) {
        mMap = map;
        mMap.getTrackingSettings()
                .setMyLocationTrackingMode(MyLocationTracking.TRACKING_FOLLOW);
        mMap.setOnMyLocationChangeListener(this::onLocationChanged);
    }

    private onLocationChanged(Location location) {
            Log.d("Map", "Mapbox location @ " + location.getLatitude() + ", " + location.getLongitude());
    }
}
```

The layout is:

```
    <com.mapbox.mapboxsdk.maps.MapView
        android:id="@+id/map"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:style_url="@string/mapbox_style_url"
        app:tilt="45"
        app:scroll_enabled="false"
        app:zoom_enabled="false"
        app:rotate_enabled="false"
        app:logo_enabled="false"
        app:attribution_enabled="false"
        app:my_location_enabled="true"
        app:compass_enabled="false"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so the issue here was the fact that the tracking mode was being reset during the initialization of the map view (and on any call to moveCamera. The solution was to add:

```
mMap.getTrackingSettings()
        .setDismissLocationTrackingOnGesture(false);
```

Answer (score 1):

I've encountered something like this as well.  I don't think it has anything to do with `TrackingSettings#setDismissLocationTrackingOnGesture(false)`, although you probably do want to call that since you're setting a tracking mode.

What you describe sounds like `TRACKING_FOLLOW` being enabled in combination with [a bug I submitted](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-native/issues/7441).  The Mapbox Android SDK uses a fused location sensor rather than plain GPS.  I've noticed that it sometimes loses my GPS location, or at least gives priority to the network-based location.  When this happens, the location accuracy circle becomes very large and the location marker drifts in the direction of the nearest cell towers.